# What is the difference between SRDF (Semantic robot description format) and SDF(simulation description format) in ROS?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the difference between these two formats . Also, can i convert a SRDF file to SDF ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299638/what-is-the-difference-between-srdf-(semantic-robot-description-format)-and-sdf(simulation-description-format)-in-ros?/) by [Robo_Panda](https://answers.ros.org/users/36827/robo_panda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2018-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-05**:
Note btw: you tagged this `ros2`, but neither SDF nor SRDF are currently used with/in ROS2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q269357.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0